# Create dictionary recursively from "graph" (database) data

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, peewee

A have a hierarchical structure mapped out in a MySQL database (that I am accessing via Peewee).  I am trying to traverse the data to re-assemble it into nested dictionaries (for final conversion into XML).

The below function walks my data down to the parent node and prints out the data I want structured in my dict:

```
def build_dict(current):
    query = (ParamLevel
            .select()
            # If we are looking for parents, we are matching on child
            .join(ParamLevelParamLevels, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on = (ParamLevelParamLevels.parent == ParamLevel.id))
            .where(ParamLevelParamLevels.child == current)
            )

    # If we have a parent node, recurse further
    if query.exists():
        parent = query.get()
        build_dict(parent)
        print('Current ParamLevel "%s" parent: "%s"' % ( current.name, parent.name ))
    else:
        print('Found root node: %s' % current.name)
```

In doing so, it prints this out:

```
Found root node: polycomConfig
Current ParamLevel "device" parent: "polycomConfig"
Current ParamLevel "device.dhcp" parent: "device"
Current ParamLevel "device.dhcp.bootSrvOptType" parent: "device.dhcp"
```

I am looking for input on how to generate the below data structure:

```
{polycomConfig : { device : { device.dhcp : { device.dhcp.bootSrvOptType: {} } } } }
```

I'm sure this is fairly straightforward but I'm rusty on implementing recursive functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with a `while` loop instead of recursion and just build the nested dict as you go. Recursion doesn't have really any benefit in this case.

```
def build_dict(current):
    print(f'Found root node {current.name}')
    temp_dict = {}
    query = (ParamLevel
            .select()
            # If we are looking for parents, we are matching on child
            .join(ParamLevelParamLevels, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on = (ParamLevelParamLevels.parent == ParamLevel.id))
            .where(ParamLevelParamLevels.child == current)
            )
    while query.exists():
        result = query.get()
        temp_dict = {result.name: temp_dict}
        query = (ParamLevel
            .select()
            # If we are looking for parents, we are matching on child
            .join(ParamLevelParamLevels, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on = (ParamLevelParamLevels.parent == ParamLevel.id))
            .where(ParamLevelParamLevels.child == result)
            )
```

Without having a way to test it I can't give you the output nor check for any bugs but you should get the gist of it.  The result you want should be in `temp_dict`.

I tested it with this:

```
d = {}
for i in range(5):
    d = {i: d}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{4: {3: {2: {1: {0: {}}}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Looking at your approach.
FWIW, in my case it gives me the reverse ordering:  {'device.dhcp': {'device': {'polycomConfig': {}}}}

I think the reason I was thinking recursion was to "bubble back" and assemble in reverse.

Comment: Works great, quite easy to understand as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to try this without a good example, but I believe this should work:

```py
def build_dict(current, root={}):
    query = (
        ParamLevel.select()
        # If we are looking for parents, we are matching on child
        .join(
            ParamLevelParamLevels,
            JOIN.LEFT_OUTER,
            on=(ParamLevelParamLevels.parent == ParamLevel.id),
        ).where(ParamLevelParamLevels.child == current)
    )

    # If we have a parent node, recurse further
    if query.exists():
        parent = query.get()
        root, parent_dict = build_dict(parent, root)
        parent_dict[parent.name] = {current.name: {}}
        return root, parent_dict[parent.name]
    else:
        root[current.name] = {}
        return root, root

answer, _ = build_dict(<starting_node>)
```

Comment: Looking at your approach, thanks.  Your code gives me:

{'device.dhcp.bootSrvOptType': {'device.dhcp': {}}, 'device.dhcp': {'device': {}}, 'polycomConfig': {}, 'device': {'polycomConfig': {}}}

which isn't quite what I need though.

Comment: @JoenarrBronarsson I updated it. Thinking more about it, you needed keep a reference to the root object, and to each 'parent' in order to modify the parent and keep the reference to the root.

Comment: Thanks, haven't been able to give it a go yet but much appreciated.